# Check stationary assumption after parameter estimation in ARMA model

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, biostatistics

I understand that given time series data, say $\{X_t: t=1,\ldots,T\}$, we usually use the Augmented Dickey–Fuller test to verify the stationarity assumption before conducting parameter estimation. Specifically, the stationarity of ARMA$(p,q)$ model:

$$
X_{t}-\phi_{1}X_{t-1}-\dots -\phi_{p}X_{t-p}=\varepsilon _{t}+\theta _{1}\varepsilon _{t-1}+\cdots +\theta _{q}\varepsilon _{t-q},
$$

requires that  all the roots of

$$
z^p- \phi_1 z^{p-1} - \dots -\phi_p  = 0   \text{ has absolute values smaller than 1} \qquad\qquad (1).
$$

**My Question:**

1. After obtaining the parameter estimates $\hat{\phi}_1,\cdots,\hat{\phi}_p$, do we need to verify whether the estimates satisfy stationarity assumption (1)?
2. According to the literature, I notice there are so few studies that consider this. Is that because the estimates are ensured to satisfy (1) and hence there is no need to do so?

Comment: "... has absolute values smaller than 1" should be "...larger than 1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for stationarity *before* fitting an ARMA model---plot the data, inspect the sample ACF and PACF, pretest for unit root (ADF or other tests), difference if necessary, etc.

You should be fairly sure that data (appropriately transformed) is stationary and that the only remaining exercise is ARMA model-selection.

Checking for stationarity after estimation is usually not necessary (although you can)---not because of any stationarity restrictions imposed on the estimator, but because of the techniques available for pretesting.

**AR(1) Example**

Suppose you're fitting AR(1) model (possibly non-stationary) 
$$
X_t - \phi X_{t-1} = \epsilon_t 
$$
to your data series. Standard way to estimate this model is OLS (equivalently, conditional MLE). There's no stationarity restriction imposed on the OLS $\hat{\phi}$.
Indeed, whether $\phi = 1$ or  $|\phi| < 1$, $\hat{\phi}$ is consistent. (In the non-stationary case, $\hat{\phi}$ is even super-consistent.)

Now if prior to estimation, you pre-tested the series for unit root with, say, non-augmented Dickey-Fuller and rejected the unit root null, your estimate $\hat{\phi}$ will always be below $1$.
This is simply because the DF test runs the same OLS regression and rejects when $\hat{\phi}$ is sufficiently below 1.

**AR(p) Example**

Now suppose you're fitting AR(p) models 
$$
\Phi(L) X_t = \epsilon_t 
$$
where $\Phi(L)$ is a lag polynomial, after pre-testing for unit root with the ADF test and rejecting the unit root null.

The ADF test essentially runs the same AR regression and test the null hypothesis
$\Phi(1) = 0$.
More precisely, the ADF regression is 
$$
\alpha(L) \Delta X_t + \Phi(1) X_{t-1} = \epsilon_t
$$
where $\Phi(L) = \alpha(L) (1-L) + \Phi(1) L$.
This is clearly equivalent to the original AR regression.

Rejecting the unit root null means $\hat{\Phi}(1) < 0$ for the estimated lag polynomial $\hat{\Phi}(L)$. Therefore you will not find a unit root for the estimated model.

The discussion extends to models with MA components, since MA components can be approximated by AR (empirically speaking).